# What does a higher reputation on programmers than SO say to you?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, software-engineering-se

I'm really hoping it doesn't scream, "[Architecture Astronaut!](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000018.html)"

Comment: What does a higher reputation on Meta Stack Overflow than... everywhere else combined... say...?

Comment: @Grace: it screams, ["Process wonk!"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10067/use-meta-as-a-moderator-gauge/10068#10068)

Comment: It says "Close this question."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

People like upvoting "soft" questions and answers.

Many of the questions on StackOverflow involve very specific technologies, technologies which 95% of us know nothing about.  It's hard to upvote such posts if you don't understand them.

However, every programmer has an opinion about [this.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3089/what-is-the-single-most-effective-thing-you-did-to-improve-your-programming-skill)

Comment: I got to 10K on Programmers.SE WAY faster than I did on SO.

Answer (score 5):

My Programmers rep is almost 3 times higher than my SO rep. To me it screams "it's easier to meaningfully answer questions on a site with a smaller audience".

Answer (score 3):

It means you spend more time on programmers than on SO, and each question gets more "face time" due to the lower overall volume of questions, attracting more votes.

Answer (score 0):

The questions on Programmers are more general and seem to be more advice oriented. I think it's easier for both answerers and voters to identify with a Programmers question regardless of their main tools of choice. As Robert Harvey said, there are diverse questions on SO that I can't even be bothered to read because I don't use a particular language, would not understand the question, have no hope of answering, and could not use the information in my work.